# Solidity want to ask a person to respond to a question by signing via their wallet

Tags: solidity, web3js

I am new to Solidity and have been trying to work out how to ask a number of people to vote on a question by signing it with their wallet.  i.e. If they sign then this means that they have voted yes for the question. If they do not sign,then I will not receive a response and thus they will default to No.  If they reject the request to sign I am not sure what response I would get back from the 3rdPartyProvider, so need to understand how to treat this as well.

I have a list of the wallet ids that I want to send this request to.

I assume that :

- I need to use the web3 library
- Can I call web3 from within Solidity (or do I have to interact with web3 via Javascript)
- If I can call it from within Solidity what code do I need to include?
- do I need to import web3.js or do I use the <require('web3')> command
- which command do I use to actually send the request for signature ?

I have looked at numerous discussions but I do not seem to have found a clear solution.

As you can see I am a bit confused, please could someone point me in the right direction.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't communicate with anything outside the blockchain using Solidity.

The entire process you describes is executed by a front end app, like ReactJS, communicating with MetaMask.

The voter will have to go to your front-end website, initiate the voting process and receive a MetaMask sign popup in response.

You'll also need a backend to record the votes of participants.

Comment: Many thanks and I understand that I need a front-end app to provide the interface to the 'voter' but can't I initiate the call to Metamask from my Solidity contract, and just call this function in my contract from the front-end app.? e.g. I can transfer tokens between accounts from within Solidity via Metamask or whatever wallet one uses.

Comment: Contracts can't initiate anything, only backend/dapps can initiate either a call to read from a contract, or a transaction that activates a contract's state changing function. Read about Ethereum smart contracts and how to use them

Comment: If the above is the answer to your question, feel free to accept it